# Express API Trying To Serve Public Files Gives 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I currently have an API setup like so...

**index.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();

const index = require('./server');

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

index.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is live at localhost:${port}`));

module.exports = index;
```

**server/index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const routes = require('../routes');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');

const server = express();

server.use(express.json());

// enhance your server security with Helmet
server.use(helmet());

// use bodyParser to parse server application/json content-type
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// log HTTP requests
server.use(morgan('combined'));

server.use(express.static(path.normalize(__dirname+'/public')));
server.use('/api', routes);

// Handle 404
server.use(function(req, res) {
  res.send('404: Page not Found', 404);
});

// Handle 500
server.use(function(error, req, res, next) {
  res.send('500: Internal Server Error', 500);
});

module.exports = server;
```

**routes/index.js**

```
const router = Router();

// enable all CORS requests
router.use(cors());
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Welcome to Timelapse Videos API'));

....
```

For some reason my public directory always returns 404 and i don't know why. 
If i add this to the **routes/index.js** :

```
router.get('/public', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(path.normalize(__dirname+'/../public'), 'index.html'));
});
```

It will return the static file but the issue is, there could be number of customer directories that have multiple images i want to return.

There is clearly an issue with my setup but i can for the life of me see whats going on. If i have an API all in an **index.js** and not split the router it seems to work.

Any help would fantastic and if you need more information please ask.

Comment: As with all `express.static()` not working questions, we need to know these things in order to diagnose and not have to guess: 1) What is the full path of __dirname, 2) what is the full path to a particular file you want served by `express.static()` (so we can see exactly how it is positioned relative to `__dirname`) and 3) What is the exact URL you are using in the browser to attempt to access the static file?  If it's coming from a tag in the HTML, show us the exact tag exactly as it is in the HTML.  If you're typing the URL into the browser bar show us exactly what you typed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i'm not sure if i found the issue but i found a work around.

On the file `server/index.js`:

**server/index.js**

```
server.use(express.static(path.normalize(__dirname+'/public')));
server.use('/api', routes);
```

If changed the top line to:

```
server.use('/api', express.static(path.normalize(__dirname+'/public')));
server.use('/api', routes);
```

The below line is overriding the top line (I think, it wasn't working so thats my thought process).

Now if change it to this:

```
server.use('/api/media', express.static(path.normalize(__dirname+'/public')));
server.use('/api', routes);
```

Works perfectly.

Hope this helps someone else as i spent a whole day on this lol.

Answer (score 0):

Try change this line:

```
server.use(express.static(path.normalize(__dirname+'/public')));
```

For:

```
server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

or

```
server.use(express.static('public'));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, both of these don't work. I'm going mad

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it appears the 'public' folder is at the root.
Just change

```
server.use(express.static(path.normalize(__dirname+'/public')));
```

to

```
server.use(express.static(path.normalize(__dirname+'./../public')));
```